# Union of subgroups of $\mathbb{C^*}$

Tags: field-theory

Let $\mathbb{ℂ^∗}$ = $\mathbb{ℂ}$\ ${0}$ denote the group of non-zero complex numbers under multiplication. Suppose

$Y_n$={$z\in \mathbb{C} |z^n=1$}

then which of the following is (are) subgroups of $\mathbb{C^*}$

> 1).$\bigcup_{n=1}^{100}Y_n$
>
> 2).$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_{2^n}$
>
> 3).$\bigcup_{n=100}^{\infty}Y_{n}$
>
> 4).$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_{n}$

solution i tried - Here $Y_{n}$ is a cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{C^*}$
but as we know that union of two subgroup is a subgroup iff one is contained in other.

we have $Y_{1}$={$1$} ,${Y_2}$={$1,-1$},${Y_3}$={$1,\omega,\omega^2$} and so on from this we see that ${Y_2}$ $\nsubseteq$ ${Y_3}$,then no  option is true.i am confused here.

Please help

Thankyou

Comment: I don't see why $Y_2$ should be contained in $Y_3$ specifically.

Comment: Also, it is entirely possible that the union of three or more subgroups is a subgroup without any of them being contained in the other (see for instance $C_2\times C_2$ being union of its three cyclic subgroups of order $2$).

Comment: so the rule is only for two subgroups?

Comment: For the purpose of your question, yes, though personally I don't quite know if it is true that for all $n\ge3$ there is some group (or abelian group) which has an irredundant cover by $n$ subgroups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be careful when using your intuition of *finite* unions on infinite unions. Your idea seems to hint that the first one probably isn't a subgroup. Indeed, if we take a $z=\exp(i\frac{2\pi}{99})$ and $w=\exp(i\frac{2\pi}{100})$, then the order of $zw$ is the least common multiple of $99$ and $100,$ which is $9900$, since the two numbers are co-prime. Hence, $zw\not\in \cup_{n=1}^{100} Y_n$, so it's not a sub-group.

For the rest, it's probably worth noting that each of the remaining sets are clearly stable under taking inverses and they all contain $1$. Thus, we simply need to check that for any two elements $z$ and $w$ of the union, $zw$ also belongs to the union.

Using this result, take $z\in Y_{2^n}$ and $w\in Y_{2^m},$ then the order of $zw$ divides $2^{n}\cdot 2^m=2^{n+m}$, so $zw\in Y_{2^{n+m}}$. So $ii)$ *is* a sub-group.

I think this should give you a fine enough idea of how to handle the last two (it goes fairly similarly).

Comment: Thankyou for your answer.